# Can I ignore a getter-based write-only property during deserialization in Java Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a legacy JSON API class that I'm evolving to remove a certain property.  It's currently at a point where the property value is always the same constant, so I would like my Java code to be just a simple `getter` with no underlying field for it.  I want to continue serializing the value until I know that all my clients have migrated off of using the value.  The object is only read by my clients, so I don't have to worry about them sending other values across.

```
public class MyType {
  private String value;

  public boolean isLegacyValue() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

That said, I don't want any test code or the like to fail if I deserialize a full value with the now-constant property.  Is there a way I can tell Jackson to serialize a setter method-only property, but ignore it on deserialization?  I tried a few different things, but I get a `UnrecognizedPropertyException` on deserialization.  I'd rather not change the global `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` just for this one property.

```
{"value": "ABC", "legacyValue": true}
```

Also acceptable would be a way to tell Jackson to include the value without including a Java field for it.

I'm aware I can add a getter in addition to my setter, or make it a field, but both those options feel like they're confusing the Java API, as it's not actually matching the constant constraint:

```
public void setLegacyValue(boolean legacyValue) {
    // No-op; only exists for Jackson deserialization
}
```

One thing I've found to work through trial and error is making it a final field.  For whatever reason, Jackson knows to handle that as a write-only constant in a way that doesn't work with the getter without matching setter.  This will be my solution if there's no way to do it with just a getter.

```
private final boolean legacyValue = true;

public boolean isLegacyValue() {
    return legacyValue;
}
```

Comment: What about either `@JsonProperty(access = READ_ONLY)` on the property or `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "legacyValue", allowGetters = true)` on the DTO class?

Comment: The `@JsonProperty` suggestion works (which is frustrating, since I thought I had tested exactly that).  `@JsonIgnoreProperties` doesn't work.

Comment: `@JsonProperty` has several options; you might have tried some different settings.

Comment: If you want to submit the `@JsonProperty` solution as an answer, I'll accept it so you get credit for it.  Otherwise, I'll go ahead and write it up myself later so this question has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson supports "one-way" properties using the `access` parameter of `@JsonProperty`. Annotate your property like this:

```
@JsonProperty(access = READ_ONLY)
public boolean isLegacyValue() {
    return true;
}
```